# How to edit css and js files in Apache Cloudstack version 4.10

Tags: java, html, ajax, customization, apache-cloudstack

In Apache cloudstack framework i am customizing ui. I want to add one more link to  #user-options div. I tried modifying css and js files. and i also restarted cloudstack. whatever changes i do is not refelecting on frontend.And how to change login page logo. If anyone knows about Cloudstack ui customization please help me. I use Mobaxterm to edit files.

i tried this in cloudstack3.css file

```
#user-options {
               background : #778765;
}
```

No changes in frontend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After editing the required file for example  "cloudstack.css" , save it and then update the corresponding zip file by give command. Each file in cloudstack has corresponding zip file that should be updated(overwritten).

Command to use in linux: 
gzip -k filename(complete path)